# Running groovy gives command not found error

Tags: macos, groovy, homebrew

I installed groovy using homebrew with `brew install groovy`.
When I run the groovy command on some file, I get this:

```
groovy afile.groovy 
/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/groovy/2.5.6/bin/../libexec/bin/startGroovy: line 293: 127.0.0.1: command not found
/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/groovy/2.5.6/bin/../libexec/bin/startGroovy: line 293: 169.254.169.254: command not found
/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/groovy/2.5.6/bin/../libexec/bin/startGroovy: line 293: 127.0.0.1: command not found
/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/groovy/2.5.6/bin/../libexec/bin/startGroovy: line 293: 169.254.169.254: command not found
/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/groovy/2.5.6/bin/../libexec/bin/startGroovy: line 293: 127.0.0.1: command not found
/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/groovy/2.5.6/bin/../libexec/bin/startGroovy: line 293: 169.254.169.254: command not found
```

When I run `brew upgrade groovy` it says `groovy 2.5.6 already installed`. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Weird... There is no [line 293 of startGroovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638985/running-groovy-gives-command-not-found-error)...  Never tried using brew to manage Groovy though, I always used SDKman!

Comment: Yeah I think it is a brew issue. When I downloaded the groovy package manually and ran it, I didn't get this error.

Comment: I can heartily recommend https://sdkman.io instead of brew for all things jdk

Comment: @tim_yates `startGroovy` has 310 lines, so it does have a line 293. See https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/apache-groovy-binary-2.5.6.zip.

Comment: @covfefe I can’t reproduce. Does it work if you install it from the official binary zip? Download and unzip https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/apache-groovy-binary-2.5.6.zip, then run `./groovy-2.5.6/bin/groovy yourfile`.